# Jest match string with array of RegExp

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have an array of RegExp and I want to test if some string match one of this RegExp using Jest, I'm not sure how to combine `.toEqual` with `expect.stringMatching` and an array of RegExp

Something like `expect('text').toEqual(matchOneRegExpAtLeast)`

Example

```
const message = 'anything you want'
const exps = ['/balasa/' , '/feuhfsuhf/' , '/yeuwyeye/']
```

And I want to test that message match at least one of exps patterns.

Comment: `expect(actual).toEqual(expect.stringMatching(pattern))`?

Comment: pattern in that case must be a single value, I have an array of patterns

Comment: And what's the logic for how those patterns should be applied? For example, if it's a pass if _any_ of them match you can combine them to a single pattern with `|` ("or" in regex). If _all_ of them need to match you could put the expectation in a loop. Give a more concrete example.

Comment: Note you can also look at https://github.com/jest-community/jest-extended for more matchers, and use those examples to write your own if nothing quite fits your needs.

Comment: You have to map the match function on the string with each of the regexes. If anyone has a truthy length, you have a match. So: `expect(arrayOfPatterns.some(pattern => string.match(pattern).length > 0).length > 0).toBe(true)`

Comment: puting in a loop could be a solution, I can't combine them with ```|```

Comment: As mentioned previously, note that the problem with tests like `expect(reduceWholeThingToASingleBoolean).toBe(true)` is that they give very poor [_diagnostics_](http://www.growing-object-oriented-software.com/figures/feedback-on-diagnostics.svg). If that test _fails_ it won't tell you what the string happened to be that didn't match any of the patterns, for example. If you introduce a regression later on, `Expected: true` `Received: false` isn't much help in figuring out what actually went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
const message = 'anything you want'
const exps = [ /balasa/, /feuhfsuhf/, /yeuwyeye/, /^anything/ ]
expect(exps.some(exp => message.match(exp))).toEqual(true)
```

It's worth pointing out that in your original post, you did not actually have "an array of RegExp" - but rather, you had "an array of strings that could be used to define RegExps". I have changed them to RegExps by removing the single-quotes around items in the array.